# Simple LINQ Query with LINQ to SQL, think I'm doing something wrong

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I have a table in my LINQ to SQL portion of my project.

[image: Screenshot]

I'm just trying to perform a simple query like so:

```
public static string GetMLBID(int fk_players_id)
{
   using (MLBDataClassesDataContext context = new MLBDataClassesDataContext())
   {
      var query = from a in context.players
                  where a.fk_player_type_id == fk_players_id
                  select a.mlb_com_id;

      foreach (var b in query)
      {
         Console.WriteLine(b.);  //<-- I don't get the properties listed in the "players" table that i linked in the imgur link.
      }
   }
}
```

From all the examples in google.. where i have "b.", the properties from the table i have should be popping up.. but that's not listed.  i only get simple LINQ operators and methods.

I feel like i'm missing something really simple.. any help?

Comment: You are getting a.mlb_com_id. That mlb_com_id is object?

Comment: mlb_com_id is a table property.  posted a picture of the table in the imgur link

Comment: I think you should be "select a" instead of "select a.mlb_com_id" since you want the entire table instead of just the id.

Comment: kk gonna try that right now failedprogramming

Comment: it worked failedprogramming!

Comment: Do not ever use that naming style in c#. Should be `fkPlayersId`.

Comment: i only used that naming style because that's exactly how the variable is spelt in the SQL table

Comment: `where a.fk_player_type_id == fk_players_id`... I suspect that this var name should be `fk_player_type_id`

Comment: Just a remark - this is LINQ to SQL - not Entity Framework.

Comment: ah okay.  someone told me using the SQL as dbml in my project is Entity Framework, i guess he was mistaken?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are only selecting the id `mlb_com_id`

```
select a.mlb_com_id;
```

Change the select clause to

```
select a;
```

This allows you to access all the public members of `a` on the result set.

---

**EDIT** by Pellared. *(The point of Pellared's addition is that the extension method syntax does not require a Select-clause and would therefore not have lead to the error)*:

You can also change the query using lamba expressions (which a lot of people prefer)

```
public static string GetMLBID(int fk_players_id)
{
    using (MLBDataClassesDataContext context = new MLBDataClassesDataContext())
    {
        var query = context.players
                  .Where(a => a.fk_player_type_id == fk_players_id);

        foreach (var b in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(b.mlb_com_id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it worked!  failedprogramming suggested same thing, but yes that's what i was doing wrong.  thank you.

Comment: appreciate the extra example.  still new to LINQ and entity framework so that really helps us that are learning

Comment: I only prefer using lambda expression when using Linq Xml :) the former is closest to Sql syntax.

Comment: i prefer lamda expressions. I find it easier to read especially after chaining.

Comment: The point of @Pellared's addition is that the extension method syntax does not require a Select-clause and would therefore not have lead to the error.

Comment: @failedprogramming Me too but I know some situations (really rare) when LINQ syntax is clearer - especially when you have some correlations in the query methods that are in the chain

Answer (score 1):

You need to get your elements as a list and you should be able to access the properties then.

```
public static string GetMLBID(int fk_players_id) {
    using (MLBDataClassesDataContext context = new MLBDataClassesDataContext())
    {
        var query = (from a in context.players
                     where a.fk_player_type_id == fk_players_id
                     select a).ToList();

        foreach (var b in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(b.first_name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You do *not* need to materialize the results as a list.  In fact, if all you're going to do is iterate the results, you're better off *not* doing this.  The query is *already* iterable.

Comment: hmm the properties still aren't showing even though i added the .ToList()

Comment: @user1189352 Did you change the select part of the query as I have in the code I posted? i.e. `select a` ?

Comment: I don't think ToList() matters in this case since the query will be executed before the context is disposed.

Comment: sorry didn't see that part of the edit until just now.  i kept seeing you edit but didn't catch that part, not sure if you added that part in your later revision